# ImageMagick - how can i set horizontal center position and custom vertical position?

Tags: php, image, text, imagemagick

i have a problem with ImageMagick. Need to write dinamic text on image but also need to set center position as in CSS `text-align:center` and custom top position (ex. `top:10px`)

can you help me ?

Thanks

example
[image]

Comment: Show us what you have got so far. Can you create the image? What size? Can you add text? Is it multi-line?

Comment: yes i have created the image what i need, with 4000x4000 size and texts, but not multi-line (if you can help with this too it will be great). this is a code
`convert -define png:bit-depth=8 -size 4000x4000 xc:transparent 
-pointsize 550 -stroke '#FF0000' -fill '#FFFFFF' -font {{font}} -draw "text 200,700 'ROBINETTE'" 
-pointsize 550 -stroke '#FF0000' -fill '#FFFFFF' -font {{font}} -draw "text 800,3260 'FAMILY'" 
-pointsize 550 -stroke '#FF0000' -fill '#FFFFFF' -font {{font}} -draw "text 180,3720 'CHRISTMAS'" -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 path`

you can see image in question's description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would do it by creating and centering each word on its own transparent background and then compositing over the main background, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
STYLE="-pointsize 550 -stroke #FF0000 -fill #FFFFFF -font Times -gravity center"  # standardise parameters
BASIC="-size 4000x600 xc:transparent"                                             # standardise parameters
convert $BASIC $STYLE -draw "text 0,0 'ROBINETTE'" w1.png    # word 1 centred on transparent
convert $BASIC $STYLE -draw "text 0,0 'FAMILY'"    w2.png    # word 2 centred on transparent
convert $BASIC $STYLE -draw "text 0,0 'CHRISTMAS'" w3.png    # word 3 centred on transparent
convert -define png:bit-depth=8 -size 4000x4000 xc:transparent w1.png -geometry +0+100 -composite w2.png -geometry +0+2800 -composite w3.png -geometry +0+3400 -composite out.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @mark-setchell, 

it would be great, if you show me how can i write "Family Christmas" text as multi-line text and not as different text

Comment: I haven't tested this - but something along these lines should work: `convert -size 4000x1200 xc:transparent $STYLE label:'FAMILY\nCHRISTMAS' w.jpg`  You may need `-delete 0 ` just before `w.jpg`

Comment: Or maybe `-flatten` just before the output file.

Comment: Mark, i got a blank image :/

in my example i'm getting this error `missing an image filename -stroke @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046.`

Comment: Hi Hayk - I am struggling too. I will keep trying and let you know if I succeed. You may have to just go with my original answer till we work it out...

Comment: Got it! This works... `convert -background none -size 4000x1200 $STYLE label:'FAMILY\nCHRISTMAS' w.png`

Comment: i resolve this one, there was a problem with `-stroke #FF0000` need to write `-stroke '#FF0000'` and after this i got new error, `no decode delegate for this image format convert` trying to fix it

Comment: huuuh, finally, have fixed this error, needed to add `;` after each `convert` command, now i'm trying to get multi-line, thanks a lot Mark for your help ;)